# Setup IPv6 network - no connectivity

Tags: ipv6, dhcpv6

I have a SonicWall TZ-300 firewall and I'm trying to setup a simple IPv6 network. Unfortunately, the Windows computer is not getting internet access (browse or `tracert -6` to google IPv6). See below my steps.

I guess there is some minor adjustment required that I'm missing. Please share your thoughts, this could set a possible solution for me.

At firewall, I've set:

```
Appliance - Base settings - Enable IPv6
Network - DNS - IPv6 (top) - specify IPv6 DNS servers manually: 2606:4700:4700::1111 and 2620:fe::fe
Network - DHCP server - IPv6 (top) - Enable DHCPv6 server
Network - DHCP server - IPv6 (top) - Add dynamic: prefix 2001:db8:abcd:12::
Network - DHCP server - IPv6 (top) - Add dynamic: range start 2001:db8:abcd:12::1
Network - DHCP server - IPv6 (top) - Add dynamic: range end 2001:db8:abcd:12::100
Network - DHCP server - IPv6 (top) - Add dynamic - DNS: domain name "test2222"
Network - DHCP server - IPv6 (top) - Add dynamic - DNS: Inherit DNS
```

The firewall interface I'm working is X3, with a cable directly to a Win10 machine. At this X3 interface I've set:

```
Interface 'X3' Settings for IPv6 - general - IP Assignment "static"
Interface 'X3' Settings for IPv6 - general - IPv6 Address 2001:db8:abcd:12::101
Interface 'X3' Settings for IPv6 - general - Enable Router Advertisement
Interface 'X3' Settings for IPv6 - advanced - Enable Listening to Router Advertisement
Interface 'X3' Settings for IPv6 - router advertisement - Enable Router Advertisement
Interface 'X3' Settings for IPv6 - router advertisement - managed
Interface 'X3' Settings for IPv6 - router advertisement - other configuration
```

At Windows 10, I've set:

```
Enabled IPv6 protocol (automatically get IPv6 address and DNS servers)
```

At Windows 10 I'm getting IPv6 address from DHCPv6 and also DNS from DHCpv6, but was getting gateway an autogenerated IPv6 (starting with "fe80") while expected value was the X3 IPv6 address. So I forced IPv6 gateway with the X3 IPv6 address:

```
New-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix "::/0" -NextHop 2001:db8:abcd:12::101
```

I've also created "access rules" from X3 to WAN allowing everything IPv6.

So, after all this done, I can't browse internet neither `tracert -6 2001:4860:4860::8888` (gets timeout). I can successfully ping interface X3. Firewall has a valid IPv6 at WAN port.

Comment: Where did you get your addressing info from? How is your external interface configured? Do your ISP support IPv6? (Yes, I appreciate that you've used IPv6 reserved for documentation - that's jolly good, but wee need some information about the setup...)

Comment: "LAN to WAN IPv6 traffic need manually added NAT[66] policy.

Different from IPv4, SonicWall Firewall does not automatically create NAT policies for interfaces assigned as DMZ or LAN ports. When connect an IPv6 client to a LAN port (e.g. X0) and intend to surf the IPv6 Internet, you need to manually create an NAT policy for this client." https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/lan-to-wan-ipv6-traffic-need-manually-add-nat-policy/170505534672880/ https://blogs.infoblox.com/ipv6-coe/you-thought-there-was-no-nat-for-ipv6-but-nat-still-exists/

Comment: @vidarlo As stated in the original question, the ISP does provide an IPv6, available at my WAN port. These IPs are for demonstration purpose only. What info do you need?

Comment: @GregAskew After your message (which I was surprised to know) I went and created a policy, but still didn't work. I'm still wondering why DHCP provided me the range and DNS, but didn't provide the default gateway. Have any tips on this?

Comment: @rd1218 Whom gave you the addresses to use for static assignment on X3?

Comment: IPv6 uses the gateway link-local address (in the `fe80::/64` range) for the gateway because it can have various networks and addresses assigned to an interface so using the gateway link-local address makes it the same for all the networks on the interface. That is what you get from the RA. RFC 4861 explains it: "_IP Source Address is a link-local address.  Routers must use their link-local address as the source for Router Advertisement and Redirect messages so that hosts can uniquely identify routers._"

Comment: @vidarlo The X3 static IP was inserted by myself, was following this guide https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/configuring-the-sonicwall-ipv6-dhcpv6-server/170505365235841/

Comment: @rd1218 Normally with IPv6 your ISP provides you with a prefix automatically via Prefix Delegation, that you can use on your internal network. I'm not familiar with sonicwall, but you either have to configure it statically from your prefix, or automatically.

Comment: @vidarlo I did receive an IPv6 from ISP, which is attached to X1 (WAN) interface. My test computer is connected via X3 interface. I created static IPv6 and DHCPv6 for X3 interface. I also created NAT to join X3 IPv6 to X1 IPv6 (from the link GregAskew provided)

Comment: You don't receive *one* IP. You receive a subnet, normally a /56 or /48, but *never* a single IP. And you don't NAT IPv6. So in short, you need the IP to configure on your WAN interface, and the subnet that is routed to that IP. If the ISP hands you *one* IP they don't support IPv6. It's not surprising that your setup is not working.

Comment: In addition, pay attention to what @RonMaupin writes. link-local for gateway is *completely* fine, and what you should expect. But your main problem is that NAT66 is... not a good idea, and you *need* a subnet, as an absolute minimum a /64, but preferably larger so that you can subnet yourself.

Comment: @vidarlo I understand your perspective on using the received /64 for internal network architecture, but I have a different approach in mind. I prefer an internal architecture independent of the received /64, employing NAT to connect each interface as outlined in the official KB documentation, making it agnostic to the received prefix.

Comment: I think the best advice is don't. IPv6 is simply not made with NAT in mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149672/discussion-between-vidarlo-and-rd1218).

Answer (score 0):

Delete the static route on the host. Not needed and is breaking things.

Default gateway as a link local in `fe80::/64` is expected. Router advertisement will find this automatically. Despite it being link local, you can still send it internet routed packets through it.

Making up my own IPs, the packet is still has the destination of `2001:db8:114:7717::1` but the host doesn't know where that is so it wraps it in a frame and sends it towards the router at `fe80::1`  Link local is sort of like layer 2 (MAC address) but its still IP, so it can be used in on link networks like the next hop router.

Be sure the router is sending router advertisements. Should be if the host is getting IP addresses out of your prefix. Not sure if this is your SonicWall model, but a relevant looking KB article looks to be [Configuring LAN / DMZ IPv6 Interfaces](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/configuring-lan-dmz-ipv6-interfaces/170505294099465/).  LAN interfaces have their prefixes, and be sure Enable Router Advertisement is checked.

Your prefix might be static, or could be dynamic via  DHCPv6 prefix delegation. Both are mentioned in that KB article. Either way, the usual concept is a big prefix on a WAN interface, and /64 subnets out of that on LAN and other interfaces.